# MongoDB Production Server: router.get 'Unexpected Identifier'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I finally have deployed my Node.js production server and I'm almost ready to go.

I am now following the Official MongoDB tutorial (https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-your-first-application-mongodb-creating-rest-api-using-mean-stack-part-2) and everything has been going fine.

Without getting too in-depth, I have just called my server.js file:

```
node server.js
```

And I received an error:

```
router.get('/feeds', stormpath.apiAuthenticationRequired, function(req, res)
^^^^^^
```

The actual error is as follows:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

After taking a look at my code, this is my **app.js** code:

```
exports.addAPIRouter = function(app, mongoose, stormpath) {

    app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
        res.contentType('application/json');
        next();
    });
    app.post('/*', function(req, res, next) {
        res.contentType('application/json');
        next();
    });
    app.put('/*', function(req, res, next) {
        res.contentType('application/json');
        next();
    });
    app.delete('/*', function(req, res, next) {
        res.contentType('application/json');
        next();
    });

    var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/user/enroll', function(req, res) {
        logger.debug('Router for /user/enroll');
        …
    }
    router.get('/feeds', stormpath.apiAuthenticationRequired, function(req, res)                     {
        logger.debug('Router for /feeds');
        …
    }
    router.put('/feeds/subscribe', 
              stormpath.apiAuthenticationRequired, function(req, res) {
        logger.debug('Router for /feeds');
        …
    }
    app.use('/api/v1.0', router);
}
```

I have been trying to figure this one out for the past 4 hours.

Has anyone run into this particular problem, while using the Ubuntu version of the MongoDB documentation? Just in case the express module wasn't being called (I believe that's where the .Router() function derives), I also added this line (but took it out after there was no change):

```
express = require('express')
```

Any ideas? I hope my question is not as broad as it sounds and the issue can be resolved without going too far outside of this function.

BTW, after using the MongoDB examples and documentation, they seem to have a bad habit of splitting code **mid-function** which can bring a little confusion to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing this route to see if your code still breaks? 

`router.get('/feeds', stormpath.apiAuthenticationRequired, function(req, res)`

I believe that you should have express imported into the file before using the router as well.

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you for the suggestion. When I comment out the first 'router.get' function, the next 'router.put' triggers the same error, so I'm sure it's a import issue. I then proceeded to add a "var express = require('express')" and directly under I entered "var router = express();". Nothing worked. The faulty code in question is part of the express example on the official website, so I will continue looking for solutions. Thanks again!

Comment: You need to initiate the router using express.Router() after you require the express module.